# In an attribute, how can I get the name of the method it is attached to?

Tags: c#, attributes, metaprogramming

I want to do this:

```
[My]
public void F()
{
}


class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyAttribute()
    {
         // I want the value "F" here
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The `CallerMemberName` even works on attribute constructors:

```
    public MyAttribute([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName]string methodName = null)
```

The attribute object doesn't get instantiated until the attribute is queried.

To see it in action, debug this program:

```
// Does not hit breakpoint
new C().F();

// does hit breakpoint
typeof(C).GetMethod("F").GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), false);
```

---

```
class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyAttribute([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName]string methodName = null)
    { // set breakpoint here and examine `methodName`

    }
}
```